# What is the word for a "ride" but from the drivers perspective

Tags: single-word-requests

When a person is trying to get from one place to another with someone driving between those two points, we say he's trying to find a "ride".

For example you can say "I'm looking for a ride to New York". Or "I got a ride to New York".
A driver can say "I gave him a ride".

But what is a "ride" from the driver's perspective? If a driver is looking for a passenger, you can't say "he is looking for a ride" since that implies he has no car to drive.

Is there a noun to describe the activity from the driver's perspective?

Comment: A hitcher, maybe? Though that doesn't cover friends you happen to be giving a ride, of course. I'd say this is so rarely needed that in the few cases where you do need to express the notion, you'd simply circumphrase: “He's looking for someone to share the journey with”, “He's looking for an extra passenger”, “He's looking for some company for the ride”, etc.

Comment: I can't think of a good single word for that ("I'm looking for a hitchhiker" doesn't sound right to me). I would say "I'm looking for a fellow traveller/fellow passenger/fellow road tripper/travel companion".

Comment: If you're a professional driver, you are probably looking for a **fare**.

Answer (score 5):

I think you would just say "I'm looking for a passenger" or maybe "I'm looking for a carpooler" depending on the context.

Answer (score 4):

If you're a driver, you can say that you gave a passenger (or a hitchhiker) a *lift*. So if you want to find a passenger, you could say:

> I am looking for someone who wants a lift to New York.

Comment: You could also use ride in this context: I am looking for someone who wants a ride to New York. The OP is asking what the "someone" in your sentence is called.

Answer (score 1):

A journey intended to be enjoyed, especially if accompanied, is called a *[road trip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Road_trip)*.

While not a single word, the driver could say she was looking for a **road buddy** or a **trip buddy**. *[Buddy](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/buddy)* can mean

> a person who does some activity with you

It has lost its exclusively male connotation and is often used, regardless of the gender of the fellow-traveler.

SUPPLEMENT:

**Most abject apologies!** I did not make clear that both of the suggested phrases are NOT standard terms or idioms, but merely suggested constructions based on the request. Also, *road trip* itself is a somewhat slang idiom.

Comment: I have never heard either of those terms actually used anywhere.

Comment: @Kevin - Neither have I, but, then again, I don't hang out around truck stops very much. I entered these terms into Google, and found some rather interesting matches on bulletin boards, blogs, dating websites for truckers, and even this one from Craigslist: _Looking for a road buddy asap im driving to dallas for a while tommorow and im looking someone who will ride with me..._

Comment: That sounds more like jargon than standard English then, and is probably not used generally enough to be understood by most people. Unless of course OP *is* hanging out in truck stops...

Comment: @KevinWorkman Please see supplement.

Comment: @J.R. Please see supplement.

Comment: @Kevin - Really? Maybe I had never heard of it before, but I didn't find it hard to understand. To be truthful, I think "standard English" might be harder to define, understand and grasp than "trip buddy" :^)

Comment: @bib - I hope you realize I was in favor of your answer before the abject apology and the (in my mind, unnecessary) clarification.

Comment: @J.R. I did't take the commentary ill. I think it is important to distinguish in an answer when a suggestion is accepted usage and when it is a neologism or other new construction. I just wasn't paying attention.

Comment: Is it a new construction? _A road buddy is someone to watch your bundle while you go get a drink_ (Anderson, 1935); _Mike Kapsa was Eckstein's road buddy throughout the campaign_ (US House hearing, 1998); _My road buddy for all these years goes deeper and deeper into his coffee_ (Gaslin, 2003); _His sister Marsha is a last minute choice for a road buddy_ (L. McGuire, 1995, Juvenile Fiction); _Your my road buddy, but I'm lonely all the time_ (from the song _Road Buddy_ by Dar Williams); _Writing to his road buddy on May 22, 1951, Kerouac announced to Cassady that he had just written a book_...

Answer (score 0):

The operator of the vehicle is looking for a **rider**. See [here](https://www.smarttrips.org/Pages/vanpool-riders-wanted) for an example (vanpool riders wanted). [Here's](http://www.piercetransit.org/needing-riders/) another one.

In these examples, the driver may be looking for riders to support a driving service or to share costs on a specific trip. (E.g., *I'm driving to Denver and I'm looking for a rider to share the costs.*)

Comment: In my question, I am asking for an equivalent of "ride" - which does not refer to a person - from the driver's perspective. A 'rider' is a person. A 'ride' is not.

Comment: I suggest that you edit your question to reflect this then. The other answers are in a similar vein: **passenger**, **carpooler**, **someone to share...**, **road buddy**, **trip buddy** and **rider**. They all refer to the person.